# How to calculate numeric age from conflicting age classes?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataset on animal captures for a series of year, which may look like this:

```
Data<-cbind.data.frame(c("A","B","A","B","C","A","B","A","B","C"),
                   c("1CY","2CY",">1CY",">2CY",">2CY",">1CY",">1CY",">2CY",">2CY",">1CY"),
                   c(2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013))
colnames(Data)<-c("ID","Age_Class","Year")

    > Data
   ID Age_Class Year
1   A       1CY 2010
2   B       2CY 2010
3   A      >1CY 2011
4   B      >2CY 2011
5   C      >2CY 2011
6   A      >1CY 2012
7   B      >1CY 2012
8   A      >2CY 2013
9   B      >2CY 2013
10  C      >1CY 2013
```

Each captured animal is assigned to an age class based on plumage characteristics. These age classes include 1CY (0 years old), 2CY (1 year old), >2CY (atleast 2 years old) and >1CY (atleast 1 year old). I would like to determine the minimum numeric age for each observed individual, which would look like this:

```
> Data
   ID Age_Class Year Age_Numeric
1   A       1CY 2010           0
2   B       2CY 2010           1
3   A      >1CY 2011           1
4   B      >2CY 2011           2
5   C      >2CY 2011           2
6   A      >1CY 2012           2
7   B      >1CY 2012           3
8   A      >2CY 2013           3
9   B      >2CY 2013           4
10  C      >1CY 2013           4
```

Thanks to the help of @Maël I can partly get there with the following:

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Age_Numeric = case_when(Age_Class == "1CY" ~ 1,
                         Age_Class == "2CY" ~ 2,
                         Age_Class == ">2CY" ~ 3 + Year - first(Year[Age_Class == ">2CY"]))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But I run into trouble trying to incorporate the >1CY age class. Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute age based on the first appearances of both `">1CY"` and `">2CY"`, and take whichever is highest:

```r
library(dplyr)

Data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Age_Numeric = case_when(
    Age_Class == "1CY" ~ 0,
    Age_Class == "2CY" ~ 1,
    Age_Class %in% c(">1CY", ">2CY") ~ pmax(
      1 + Year - first(Year[Age_Class == ">1CY"]),
      2 + Year - first(Year[Age_Class == ">2CY"]),
      na.rm = TRUE
    )
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   ID    Age_Class  Year Age_Numeric
   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 A     1CY        2010           0
 2 B     2CY        2010           1
 3 A     >1CY       2011           1
 4 B     >2CY       2011           2
 5 C     >2CY       2011           2
 6 A     >1CY       2012           2
 7 B     >1CY       2012           3
 8 A     >2CY       2013           3
 9 B     >2CY       2013           4
10 C     >1CY       2013           4
```

PS - with dplyr >=1.1.0, you could use `case_match()` and `.by` instead of `case_when()` and `group()` / `ungroup()`:

```r
Data %>% 
  mutate(
    Age_Numeric = case_match(
      Age_Class,
      "1CY" ~ 0,
      "2CY" ~ 1,
      c(">1CY", ">2CY") ~ pmax(
        1 + Year - first(Year[Age_Class == ">1CY"]),
        2 + Year - first(Year[Age_Class == ">2CY"]),
        na.rm = TRUE
      )
    ),
    .by = ID
  )
```